# How to retrive data from python http.server response

Tags: python-3.x, get, http.server

```
from http.server import test, ServerHTTPRequestHandler

test(ServerHTTPRequestHandler)
```

output:

```
Serving HTTP on 0.0.0.0 port 8000 (http://0.0.0.0:8000/) ...

10.10.10.10 - - [20/Jul/2023 08:32:33] "GET /?name=test HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

How can I save the above data in a variable and use it later.

If I use ^c the program get's exited